# How to restrict Django models from using certain foreign key values?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a Django model that has a "successor" field, which is a foreign key to that same model. I want to restrict the model from ever being able to (1) set an instance to be its own successor or (2) create a circular predecessor-successor relationship.

This would be simple if Django called `clean` before saving, but apparently it doesn't.

I essentially want to call the validators in the `clean`, `add_predecessor`, and `add_successor` methods below whenever a model is saved.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    successor = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

...

    def clean(self):
        if self.successor is self:
            raise Exception("...")

    def add_predecessor(self, predecessor):
        if predecessor is self:
            raise Exception("...")
        if self.successor is predecessor:
            raise Exception("...")
        predecessor.successor = self

    def add_successor(self, successor):
        if successor is self:
            raise Exception("...")
        if successor.successor is self:
            raise Exception("...")
        self.successor = successor
```

I could override `save`, but that seems like a heavy-handed solution.

Comment: Here you only check for cycles with "length" one and two (for example `a -> b -> c -> a` is still possible). Is that "by design", or do you want to prevent all sorts of cycles?

Comment: As for `clean`, it is only called by `Form`s and some other Django components, but it is correct that Django ORM calls do not use clean, mainly for performance reasons if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Hm I probably do want to prevent all cycles, I just hadn't thought that far ahead yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use pre_save signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save,sender=MyModel)
def pre_save_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # some case
    if case_error:
        raise Exception('OMG')
```

also you can override save method of `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #check your conditions and raise exception
    ....
```